# Column resize issue in bootstrap 4 - make last cols fill width of row

Tags: for-loop, dynamic, responsive-design, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Hello I having issue with maintained the column in different screens and number.

Right now I have 
3 column per row in desktop 
4 column per row in ipad
2 column per row in mobile

Now in desktop I have to resize column width like If i have total 7 columns
so i display 3 column in 1st row then next 3 column on 2nd row and last 7th column in 3rd row but on last column i need to change its with that equal to above 3 column width.

Same case when i have total 8 column I'll attached picture for more explain

guide required for this :)

[image]

code

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 portfolio-girdz col-6" style="margin-left:-1px;">
        <div class="cbp-item-wrapper">
            <a href="#" class="cbp-caption cbp-singlePage">
                <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">
                    <img src="/images/activities.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                    <div class="c-masonry-border"></div>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="/activities" class="cbp-l-grid-work-title cbp-singlePage">activities</a>

        </div>


    </div>
```

Comment: code added actually its come dynamically & I am using handbar with node js

Comment: @ZimSystem yes :) its long story to use both will change it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great use-case for the [`flex-grow` utility class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#grow-and-shrink) recently added in Bootstrap 4.1.0. Use `flex-grow-1` and `mw-100` to have the cols evenly fill width when there is more space on the row....

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4 mw-100 flex-grow-1">
            <div class="card bg-info"></div>
        </div>
        ...
</div>
```

[Demo (last cols fill width)](https://www.codeply.com/go/64JMDz53GZ/last-col-fill-remaining-width)

---

Note: This can also be done with CSS (instead of `mw-100 flex-grow-1`):

```
.row>.col-6 {
    max-width: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Comment: great is it only available on bootstrap 4.1.0 not in 4.0

Comment: Yes, only 4.1 but easy to add CSS as shown above for 4.0